# Cloning harddrive I/O errors after about 30 seconds

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone, dd, clonezilla

I am trying to clone a harddrive with important data to another harddrive to make sure we can keep those files safe.

Now my old HD is a 500GB 3.5" and the new one is 1TB 3.5". My old HD is plugged directly to my computer and the new HD is plugged with an HD enclosure.

Once I mount the harddrive, I see all the files, no problem. I can copy some files over without a problem. But when I try to copy all files over, its starts to transfer them and then stops after 30 seconds and all files on the old HD are unreadable.

Now, I tried using Clonezilla to clone the old HD to the new HD. It started copying and then after about 30 seconds it said "Could not complete".

When I try and clone the HD by using dd, it give me "I/O errors, 0 bytes transferred".

Any solutions for this? What could be the problem?

Thanks everyone,

Comment: Have you just tried copyin the important ones?

Comment: We have about 20GB of pictures. 30 seconds after starting to copy them over, the files become unreadable. I need to be able to move them all over to the new HD.

Comment: Try using `dd_rescue` instead.  It will skip over bad sectors.

Comment: Clonezilla also has a "rescue" option.

Comment: How do I use the "rescue" option? Do you have a link perhaps? @DarthAndroid

Comment: Last I saw, there was just a (sadly, hidden) checkbox labelled `-rescue` under expert mode: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/forums/forum/663168/topic/3536957

Answer (score 1):

To answer "What could be the problem?", I suggest a review of permissions. If the permissions  are set to limit access or function, it could result in the situation you are describing.

Open "Computer">Right click your source drive (or open to a particular file, if you are pulling over certain files)
Click ***security*** tab
Click ***Edit***
Tick ***Allow*** for all users
Click ***OK***

Comment: This is on Windows OS?

Comment: @Karl Yes That would be for Windows.